# Unable to load iframe content into a modal properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following demo. Why am I not able to load the content into Modal body properly? I tried two ways of

**1-** In this scenario I put the dom of `.widget` inside the `.modal-body`. This is loading the content into modal, but the calculation is not happening correctly.

While the down-payment inputs must be in this format:

[image]

when I pass an input I am only getting all in 20%

[image]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.ratehub.ca/assets/js/widget-loader.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch Calculator
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<div class="widget" data-widget="calc-payment" data-purchase="only" data-province="BC" data-lang="en"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2-** In this scenario I tried load the dom of `.widget` inside the `.modal-body` after showing the modal.

```
$(".btn-primary").on("click", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".modal-body").append('<div class="widget" data-widget="calc-payment" data-purchase="only" data-province="BC" data-lang="en"></div>');
  }, 2000);

});
```

but I am not able to load any thing there. I also tried `.html()` functions instead of `.append()` but not able to load any thing there.

Comment: I ran your code snippet for the first example and did not see an issue with the down payment values.

Comment: but if you pass for example `2000000` in the asking price the all down payments change to `20%`

Comment: Can you give the code that does the calculations and populates those fields? I see that if I add anything below 1 million it seems to work fine...

Comment: @MonaCoder must be some flawed logic in the button click event

Comment: @Rayan, agreed since this is acting properly while is in regular page! but what is it?

Comment: I've no problem with 2.000.000 or 20.000.000. It calculates correctly. No- yes now the problem apears. Maybe there are sessionStorrage things - that don't work in modal-box.

Comment: thta's strange! I am getting all in 20% foe down-payments even here in stack over flow sand box!

Comment: I've run through this as well. Below $500,000, the minimum down payment is 5%. At $500,000, it's .0001% of the asking price. This percentage decreases on a sliding scale to .000075% at $999,999. This is all presumably as you want it. Where it gets strange for me is that if I then increase the asking price to $1,000,000, the down payment percentages jump abruptly to 20%, 25%, 30% and 35%. Unless there is a strange law in Vancouver (well, there are plenty of strange laws in Vancouver, of course), then this doesn't make sense to me. Perhaps there's an error in there somewhere once you hit $1m?

Comment: Thanks Bob bu I test this in many different style. The calculator is functioning well when is not rendering in a display normal content. But when ever you load it into a dynamic content like bootstrap Modal I am getting this kind of errors. I also tried it in fancybox jquery plugin and same thing happend there. By the way , cant' be more agree on what you said on Vancouver!